# What is "appear to be telling gentlemen how ignorant they are while giving the ladies a pass" intended to mean?

Tags: comprehension

Source: [C++ For Dummies, 7th Edition](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-111882377X.html) by Stephen R. Davis (2014)

Example:

> Use of gender is always a tricky subject when writing a how-to book. **I don’t
>   want to appear to be telling gentlemen how ignorant they are while giving
>   the ladies a pass by using he and him all the time.** In this book, I use the
>   pronouns she and her when referring to the programmer and he and him
>   when referring to the user of the program. So, she writes a program that he
>   can use.

I don't think I can comprehend that sentence well enough. To me, it's not clear at all what exactly he's trying to say there. Exactly is the operative word here. This is what I'm able to get out of the sentence: He doesn't want men to look stupid as he gives the ladies a pass (they're not gong to be included because he's not going to use female-based pronouns) by using only the traditional English masculine pronouns he and him all the time. But how does using only male-based pronouns like he and him all the time in a textbook, and to tell you the truth this is something that has been done for centuries in English literature, make men seem ignorant? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: He's explaining why he's using the pronoun "she" instead of "he"... Since English doesn't have a genderless singular pronoun.

Comment: Cookie Guy what happened? Your question titles used to be good and descriptive. :(

Comment: @Catija not sure I believe _it_.

Comment: @imallett Referring to **people** using "it" is specifically cruel and never done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A paraphrase

> If I use the pronouns *he* and *his* all the time in this book when explaining things, it might make it seem that I am saying *men* are the only ones who need to be instructed, and that *women* do not, but this is not the case; {therefore I will use the convention I describe in the next sentence}.

For *to give someone a pass,* see [this answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/146724/153649). It is basically to leave someone out or not include someone.

---

For the topic of *they/their* as a gender-neutral singular pronoun, see

[Is there a correct gender-neutral, singular pronoun ("his" versus "her" versus "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus).

Comment: Okay. Now everything makes perfect sense.

Comment: Renaat Declerck did the something similar in one of his books: used She for the Speaker and He for the Hearer whenever those personae were required.